# Capturing HD screenshot of screen using java?

Tags: java, screenshot

I have recently studied about capturing screen shot in java using **Robot** class. I have implement following code for that.

```
public class Beginning implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private static long counter = 0;
    private final int FRAME_CAPTURE_RATE = 124;
    private Robot robot;

    public Beginning() throws Exception {
        robot = new Robot();
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Beginning beginning = new Beginning();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("D:\\CapturedFrame\\toolImage" + counter + ".png"));
                counter++;
                thread.sleep(FRAME_CAPTURE_RATE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Something fishy is going on...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a output of this code I am getting images of size 1024x1024 but these are not HD images, Can anyone please suggest me that how to modify this code to capture screenshots in HD formats. Thanks in advance.

**I just want that, presently in my stored .png image single pixel value is stored in 8-bits, I want to change this to 16-bits or higher**.

Comment: What's the size of your screen??

Comment: @MadProgrammer, 1024x1024

Comment: So why would you expect any different?

Comment: Also, define *"HD Images"*

Comment: Yea, you can't get HD unless you get a bigger screen.

Comment: actually in these images when i am using for further image processing then i am not able to process these images due to low intensities.

Comment: *"process these images due to low intensities"* - Think you might need to explain further